# Category of sets has a strict initial object

Tags: category-theory

Since **Set** is cartesian closed, its initial object, $0 = \varnothing$ is strict. Consider the object $A = \{ 1, 2 \}$. There is no isomorphism (bijection) $f : A \to 0$, since the cardinalities are different. So how is it that $0$ is a strict initial object? There must be something I'm missing about isomorphisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no isomorphisms $A\to \varnothing$, this is true. However, this is not a problem as there aren't any morphisms $A\to \varnothing$ at all.

If an initial object $0$ in a category is not a strict initial object, there must be some morphism $f:X\to 0$ which is not an isomorphism. The only morphism in **Set** with $\varnothing$ as codomain is the identity map $\varnothing \to \varnothing$, which is an isomorphism. So $\varnothing$ is a strict initial object.

Comment: Does the empty function not count as a morphism?

Comment: @user514088 Yes, but the empty function can't have $A$ as domain. What would $f(1)$ be?

Comment: Ahh. Thank you!